# Upgraded to 16.04, "The system is running in low graphics mode", and Windows is missing from grub

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, drivers, amd-graphics

First, i apologize for sloppiness. I am using mobile app for first time.
I simply upgraded through software upgrader. I am now met with The system is running in low graphics mode. I have AMD/ATI Tahiti xti graphics. So i first tried

`sudo apt-get install fglrx`

My result was
 "package fglrx has no installation candidate".
Since i wasn't sure that was the issue, i moved on. I tried to see how much space i had with

`df -h`

and i see that i have more than 90% space being used. This might be the culprit, but trying to delete xsession-errors does not seem to work. It's only my guess that this disc space is being taken up by errors, because my desktop usage is minimal and last i checked, i had a great deal of free space (before upgrade)
I did a full backup of Ubuntu partition before upgrading, so i wouldn't mind simply restoring the old desktop, if i could figure out how. 
Also, this is a dual boot situation, and i notice Windows is no longer in grub.
`sudo update-grub` 
does nothing for me.

Intel core i7-3770 ivy

16GB ram

Msi r9 280x video card

Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04+ removed FGRLX packages. "amdgpu" and the opensource "radeon" drivers are the currently default installed kernel drivers. I'd suggest upgrading the kernel first, to 4.8+. To install the 16.10 kernel, use this:

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04

Note: this will update your 16.04.1 installation to 16.04.2, and enable HWE. Kernel 4.8 will also be installed.

If this doesn't work, I'd suggest manually installing a newer mainline kernel. 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/